# Use of て-form + に

Tags: usage, syntax

A friend recently wrote (in response to a compliment):

嬉しい！嬉しく**てに**やけてしまいました。

I understand the meaning entirely, but it's the first time I've come across て form followed immediately by に。A quick search of sample sentences on Jisho.org, as well as a peek through my grammar book, revealed nothing. Is this a common (or even grammatically correct) usage?

Answer (score 2):

You're not parsing it correctly, I'm afraid. It's 「嬉しくて、にやけてしまいました。」（にやける = to grin, smirk）

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you. I was thinking she had used やける as some kind of slang for blushing, which also seemed strange. Turns out I was wrong on both accounts, haha.  勉強になりました！